# How to stop Algolia from indexing posts with noindex in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, algolia

Im using Algolia on my website gintlemen.com and i dont want posts, that are set to noindex via Yoast SEO Plugin to be indexed by Algolia.

I found this post https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/indexing-flow.html, but im not sure where to put the snippet.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 2):

To exclude posts marked as 'noindex' by Yoast, you need to add the following snippet to the `functions.php` of your active theme.

```
<?php
/**
 * Don't index pages where the robot index option
 * in the Yoast SEO plugin is set to noindex.
 *
 * @param bool    $should_index
 * @param WP_Post $post
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function filter_post( $should_index, WP_Post $post )
{
    if ( false === $should_index ) {
        return false;
    }

    return get_post_meta($post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_meta-robots-noindex', true) == 1 ? false : true;
}

// Hook into Algolia to manipulate the post that should be indexed.
add_filter( 'algolia_should_index_searchable_post', 'filter_post', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'algolia_should_index_post', 'filter_post', 10, 2 );
```